# Create a Polygon using Java on Mouse move Event

Tags: java, swing, graphics, maps

I want to create a polygon `onMouseMove()` event.

Here is what I've tried:

```
public DrawingListners(JMapPane mappane) {
    this._Pane = mappane;
    this._Pane.addMouseListener(new MapMouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onMouseClicked(MapMouseEvent ev) {
            if (ev.getClickCount() == 2 && _Drawing == Drawings.Polygon) {
                CreateFeatureCollection();
                addPolygonToFC(poly);

                for (int i = 0; i < nNumbers; i++) {
                    System.out.println(poly.xPoints[i] + ":" + poly.yPoints[i]);
                }

                notifyParent.firePropertyChange(CallType.Drawing.toString(), null, null);
                dragged = false;
                graphics.dispose();
                graphics = null;
                startPos = null;
                poly = null;
                nNumbers = 0;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMousePressed(MapMouseEvent ev) {
            if (enabled) {
                startPos = new Point(ev.getPoint());
                if (_Drawing != Drawings.Marker)
                    dragged = true;
                if (poly == null) {
                    poly = new pMapPolygon();
                }
                poly.addPoint(startPos.x, startPos.y, nNumbers);
                nNumbers++;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMouseMoved(MapMouseEvent ev) {
            if (enabled && poly != null) {
                ensureGraphics();
                if (_Drawing == Drawings.Polygon) {
                    poly.addPoint(ev.getPoint().x, ev.getPoint().y, nNumbers);
                    //graphics.drawPolygon(poly.xPoints, poly.yPoints, poly.xPoints.length);

                    graphics.setColor(Color.blue);
                    graphics.fillPolygon(poly.xPoints, poly.yPoints, poly.xPoints.length);
                    //graphics.drawPolygon(poly.xPoints, poly.yPoints, poly.xPoints.length);

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMouseDragged(MapMouseEvent ev) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onMouseReleased(MapMouseEvent ev) {

        }

        private void ensureGraphics() {
            if (graphics == null) {
                graphics = (Graphics2D) _Pane.getGraphics();
                graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                graphics.setXORMode(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
class pMapPolygon {
int[] xPoints = new int[500];
int[] yPoints = new int[500];
int nNumber = 0;

public pMapPolygon() {
}

public void addPoint(int x1, int y1, int number) {
    // System.out.println(x1 + ":" + y1);
    if (number == 0) {
        for (int i = number; i < xPoints.length; i++) {
            xPoints[i] = x1;
            yPoints[i] = y1;
        }
    } else {
        xPoints[number] = x1;
        yPoints[number] = y1;
    }

    nNumber = number;
}
}
```

What do I need to do to achieve this? What am I doing wrong?

I have Created a Polygon Class `pMapPolygon` which has the required parameters `xPoints` and `yPoints` and a function to add points to arrays that store all the `x` and `y`'s.

I have called that particular function `addPoint()` in `onMousePressed()` and `onMouseMoved()`. But when I start the application, it doesn't produce the correct polygon...

Comment: what universe are you in?? what language is this??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide context, such as the name of the components you're using. Also describe what's going wrong: If it doesn't produce the correct polygon, tell us the difference between the correct polygon and the one it produces. Or show screenshots. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a question that can be answered promptly and accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It take a while to suggest a proper way to draw in map control, you need to override paintComponent method of your map control.

```
@Override
 protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);
       if (drawingLock.tryLock()) {
            try {
                 Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                 if (baseImage != null) {                        
                       g2.drawImage(baseImage, imageOrigin.x, imageOrigin.y, null);
                 }
                 if (this._Drawing != null) {
                       if (this.poly != null && this._Drawing == Drawings.Polygon) {                             
                            //g.setColor(Color.gray);
                            g2.fillPolygon(this.poly.xPoints, this.poly.yPoints, this.poly.xPoints.length);
                       }
                       if (this.rect != null && this._Drawing == Drawings.Rectangle) {
                            //g.setColor(Color.gray);
                            g2.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
                       }
                       if (this.rect != null && this._Drawing == Drawings.Oval) {
                            //g.setColor(Color.gray);
                            g2.fillOval(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
                       }
                       if (this.ln != null && this._Drawing == Drawings.Line) {
                            //g.setColor(Color.black);
                            g2.drawLine(ln._x1, ln._y1, ln._x2, ln._y2);
                       }
                 }                    
            } finally {
                 drawingLock.unlock();
            }
       }
 }
```